# Error finding tcl.init when running Git GUI

Tags: git, tcl

I get the following error message when I try to start the Git GUI:

> Error in Wish
>
> Can't find a usable init.tcl in the
>   following directories: ... [list of
>   directories follows, init.tcl is in
>   the first one listed]
>
> This probably means that Tcl wasn't
>   installed properly.

I'm running Windows 7 and I'm sure this problem is related to that, but I don't know where to start. I can, and most often will, use the Bash tool, but it annoys me that this doesn't work.

I installed the msysgit package: Git-1.7.0.2-preview20100309.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem (win7 prof. 32bit) and just found out that everything runs as it should, as soon as I try running gitk as administrator.

Edit: it also helps to change permissions for git/bin/wish.exe to "always run as administrator", though it'll then ask for administrator credentials any time I run gitk.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense and fits with another similar experience I had with another program. I just didn't connect the dots.

Answer (score 3):

It was reported in [issue 121](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=121) as an "issue with `TCL` and `NTFS` junction points, and not Git on Windows."
([junction point](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524) = [symlink for local directories on Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point))

You will find in [issue 301](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=301) various test to make in order to reinstall msysgit (or TCL only), to see if the problem persists.

> Rather than delete a number of programs to try ensure a specific version of `Tcl/Tk`
>   you can instead just modify the `git.cmd` batch script and feed it a specific
>   executable path.
>   For instance, if you download a `tclkit` executable (a standalone
>   single-file Tcl/Tk executable) you can modify the last line in `git.cmd` (in the
>   `Program Files\Git\cmd` folder) so that it looks like:

```
:gui
@if "%2"=="citool" @goto default
@start c:\opt\bin\tclkit.exe "%git_install_root%\libexec\git-core\git-gui" -- %2 %3
%4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

> Tclkit will absolutely not look outside itself for any `tcl/tk` related files.
>   It is a Tcl and Tk runtime with a virtual filesystem bound onto the executable and it will
>   only look inside this virtual filesystem for files needed by the runtime.
>   I use this approach to test tcl 8.6 versions with `git-gui` and `gitk`. This also makes it easier to check different versions of Tcl/Tk to see if your issue is related to a particular release.
>   Likewise you can install `ActiveTcl` and provide the path to the `ActiveTcl wish.exe` file.
>   The other thing you could try is to edit the `libexec/git-core/git-gui.tcl` script and
>   add the following line near the top (maybe after the 'evil concept' comment:

```
console show
```

> This will cause the Tk console to be shown and you can enter commands into this while
>   `git-gui` is running. You can then use the introspection commands (`info`, `winfo`, `wm` and `bind`) to look at the state of the system.
>   If I was to try and prevent minimization I think I'd have to hook up the Visibility event. We can check what events are bound using '`bind .`' which returns a list of all the bound events for the main window.
>   Nothing suspicious on my version (`<Configure>`,`<Map>` and `<Visibility>` would be
>   suspicious IMO).

Comment: Thanks so much. I will have a good look at this when I get home this evening!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem during my last installation of ns2.35 in ubuntu 11.04.
After I install ns2.35, got message of successful installation of ns. Then I set path in /.bashrc. Then I gave ns command which gave me same error which you got.

The problem is because, ns executable is also at /usr which is conflicting.

Solution: 
1. Go to location root-usr-local-bin by giving following command in terminal
cd /usr/local/bin
2. There you would find the ns file. We just need to remove it by giving following command
rm ns
3. Thats it, you are done. Now your ns starts running successfully.

Hope this would help you solve the problem.
Happy Learning.....